# printf - "unexpected" output with a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I have got a challange from a friend of mine.
as part of this challange I wrote a function to get a `int` from a `String`, the function gets an array of `chars` and a pointer to a number, an index.

To check if this function works I ran it with 2 numbers and watched the output. 
In my `main` I printed 4 values:

```
int t = 0;
printf("%d -> %d, %d -> %d\n", t, getNumber("99", &t), t, getNumber("as48", &t));
```

As it should be, I should have got: `0 -> 99, 2 -> 48`. 
The output was: `2 -> 99, 0 -> 0`.

After few tests I saw that it prints `t` as it is after the function is over and that it does the last function call first.
I understood that it makes sense: in `Assembly`, the last argument is being pushed to the stack first so when it is poped, the arguments would be in the right order.

My questions are: 
Can I print it in a "normal" way so it will look as it "should"? How?

Comment: This is undefined behavior.  The variable `t` is modified in two places in the argument list to `printf`, and its value is also used in the argument list.  You need to move the calls to `getNumber` out of the argument list, then print the results using 4 separate variables.  Alternatively, you can split the `printf` into multiple calls to reduce the number of variables needed.

Comment: *according to the arguments, t = 0 and the number from 0 position in the array is 99. t updates to 2 in the first call to the function and 48 is the number inside the string from 2 posiiton*  No.  *Every evaluation in the calling function (including
other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the
execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to
the execution of the called function.*  [See **6.5.2.2 Function calls**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I print in in a "normal" way so it will look as it "should"? How?

The order of evaluation of arguments of a function in C is not guaranteed. So, the answer is **NO**.
Also note that the `printf` function call invoke undefined behavior as order of evaluation of its arguments are *unsequenced*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C++ instead.

While I don't know how you have implemented the `getNumber()` function, you can use the `stoi()` function from the `string` library.

```
int stoi (const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

It basically converts a string to integer. `stoi` parses `str` interpreting its content as an integral number of the specified base, which is returned as an `int` value.

If `idx` is not a null pointer (`nullptr`), the function also sets the value of `idx` to the position of the first character in `str` after the number.

So assuming all your numbers are going to be `base 10`, you can use something like this

```
int i = std::stoi ("as48", nullptr, 10);
int j = std::stoi ("99", nullptr, 10);
printf ("%d %d\n", i, j);
```

You can use `idx` in place of `t` to get the index at which the numerical part starts - `std::string::size_type idx;` and pass it as parameter to the `stoi()` function instead of `nullptr`.

Comment: `You can do this in C++ instead.` is not considered constructive. Why not in perl, python and java, if I may ask?

Comment: If the OP knows C, and just this function `stoi()` they can implement the program they are looking to in C++ (without having to make any significant changes to their code), thus solving their problem. However, they would need to know  perl, python and java to be able to do it in those languages.

Comment: umm..did I miss a `c++` tag in the question?

Comment: Question is tagged `c`, so C++ answers are irrelevant here.

Comment: I understand - what is the protocol to help with a workable solution in such a situation?